# 10GBase-T on Cat5e cabling

Tags: 10gbethernet, cat5e

I accidently connected our new servers with our 10g switches using Cat5e S/FTP instead of Cat6a. Cablelength is 1 meter. There is a failover cluster running on the servers, without any traffic though (new gear). Is it enough to fix this in a couple of days or should i do it basically right now since the cluster could break due to network problems?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look and see if there are any errors accruing on the switch ports or the server's NIC ports - ideally before/after an extended session sending a lot of traffic in both directions.  If the counters are staying clean then it will *probably* be OK for a few days but it's something that's so cheap and easy to fix that there's no reason to leave it in place any longer than you have to.

Comment: Good common-sense answer. [Cables cost $2](http://www.provantage.com/tripp-lite-n201-001-bl~7TRPA1QU.htm). Replace the cables at your leisure.